# How to forbid drag'n drop for a Windows XP folder?

Tags: windows-xp, permissions, file-permissions

Some of users here sometimes mistakenly drag'n drop a folder. Is it possible to forbid them to move and rename a folder? They are all using Windows XP. The folder is on the network. They should be able to still create new folder and to change all the files inside the folder.

Here is an example:

```
\\network-folder\projects\folderX
```

I shouldn't be able to move or rename folderX, but I must be able to create folderY; add, delete and change files inside folderX.

This isn't really a security feature, it is just to prevent mistakes.

Comment: Security comprises three legs - confidentiality, integrity and availability.  You are discussing the latter, so it is a security question, per se.  The damage is likely inadvertent and non-malicious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing built into the OS, sorry. There might be a commercial add-on that does this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible within the  restrictions you list.  If the user must still be able to create a new folder and copy files, you have described the atomic steps necessary to move a folder except the deletion of the original.  At that point, stopping the folder delete doesn't accomplish much.

We do this by having a web service intermediate user actions, but that is beyond the scope...

Answer (score 1):

As mfinni has already said, nothing built in. Windows simply does not have that level of granularity. From my very brief exposure to Netware many years ago I seem to recall it had much finer control, so it's certainly possible that a 3rd party layer on top of the OS may be able to provide the controls you require, although I've never personally come across such a product. Of course I also haven't been looking for it.